# Undefined reference to nlopt_... symbols

Tags: fortran, nlopt

I am fairly new to Fortran and this may sound like a silly question. I encounter an error when compiling the Fortran code that is posted as an example in the NLOPT Wiki.

I compile in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the following command:

```
gfortran example-nlopt.f90 -o example-nlopt -I/usr/local/include/
```

The following error is produced in the terminal:

```
/tmp/ccbAim6b.o: In function `MAIN__':
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `nlo_create_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `nlo_get_lower_bounds_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `nlo_set_lower_bounds_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `nlo_set_min_objective_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `nlo_add_inequality_constraint_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `nlo_add_inequality_constraint_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `nlo_set_xtol_rel_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `nlo_optimize_'
example-nlopt.f90:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `nlo_destroy_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] und use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Are you sure you tried to search what does "Undefined reference" mean? There are thoudands of questions about this error. Yoou must link the library when compiling. I am sure that we must have some duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I saw in nlopt's documentation (https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Installation/#changing-the-installation-directory) it looks like you just need to specify the library to link against.  Maybe try this:

```sh
gfortran  -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib example-nlopt.f90 -o example-nlopt -lnlopt -lm
```

This assumes you have the libnlopt.so in /usr/local/lib, if not then point to its location with the -L option.